# Change image on hover using asp:imagebutton and CSS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, css

I have the following code but it doesnt seem to work:

```
<td align="center" style="padding-bottom:52.5px">
<asp:ImageButton CssClass="RightArrow" ID="Image2" runat="server"     ImageUrl="/_layouts/Right_GrayArrow.png"/>
</td>
```

And a CSS class to change image on hover:

```
.RightArrow:hover
{
background-image: url('/_Layouts/Right_GreenArrow.png') !important;
}
```

Please advise. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `ImageButton` controls renders as a `<input type="image" />` element with the `ImageUrl` property becoming the `src` attribute like:

```
<input type="image" src="/_layouts/Right_GrayArrow.png" />
```

Therefore you are applying a background image to this, which you cannot see as the `src` image is being overlayed on top of it.

You have 2 choices:

---

1) Change the `ImageButton` to use a background image:

```
.RightArrow
{
  width: /* width of image */
  height: /* height of image */
  background-image:url('/_layouts/Right_GrayArrow.png');
}
.RightArrow:hover
{
  background-image: url('/_Layouts/Right_GreenArrow.png');
}
```

If you are going to use this method though, I would recommend using an `<asp:Button />` instead. It seems pointless using an `<asp:ImageButton />` if you're not even making use of the `src` attribute.

---

2) Use jQuery to change the image on hover:

```
$(".RightArrow").hover(function(){
   $(this).attr("src", "/_Layouts/Right_GreenArrow.png");
},
function(){
   $(this).attr("src", "/_Layouts/Right_GrayArrow.png");
});
```

Worth noting this will only work with javascript enabled, and you must include the jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks! I did try the first option and couldnt get it to work. Must have missed something. The second option looks pretty good too!

Comment: Update: The first option worked! I had mispelt my class name. Thanks again!

Comment: so tired of seeing JQuery answers on non JQuery questions

Comment: @RustyH Me too ;)  Javascript equivalent, could use something like this: document.getElementById('<%=ibtnMyImageButton.ClientID %>').src = "/_Layouts/Right_GreenArrow.png"

Answer (score 7):

I prefer this way:

```
<asp:ImageButton CssClass="RightArrow" ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_layouts/Right_GrayArrow.png" onmouseover="this.src='/_layouts/Right_GreenArrow.png'" onmouseout="this.src='/_layouts/Right_GrayArrow.png'"/>
```

bye

Comment: While i like the flexibility of the CSS this is a viable option in some instances.

Answer (score 1):

The ImageUrl property isn't the same as setting the background-image.  Remove the CSS and set the onmouseout and onmouseover properties in your page.